# Extracting string between multiple occurrence of same delimiter in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, substring

Column "Test" has strings with multiple occurrence of same delimiter. Am trying to fetch the string which is within those delimiters. Can you please help.

**Example:**

```py
Test
|||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A
```

My code:

```
df["Fetch"]=df["Test"].str.rsplit("|", 2).str[-2]
```

But its giving me an output as `POC-RM0EP7-01-A`.

Am looking to get "**CHNBAD**" from the string

Comment: Let's us know if any clarification required on the answers.  See if any answer below fulfills your need.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following. We could use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function pf Pandas here. Applying `str.extract` function on `Test` column and creating new column named `Fetch` in DataFrame.

```
df['Fetch'] = df['Test'].str.extract(r'^\|+([^|]*)\|.*',expand=False)
```

DataFrame's will be as follows:

```
    Test                            Fetch
0   |||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A    CHNBAD
```

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^\|+     ##Matching 1 or more matches of | from starting of value.
([^|]*)  ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything till next | comes.
\|.*     ##Matching | and everything till last of value.
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to use '\|.*' to extract everything till last of value but my "everything" is a string that have \n on it, like "|AAA\neee\n" and '\|.*' stops on the first \n. Any idea of solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is the solution:

```py
import re

def clean_text(text):
    match = re.search(r'[|]+([A-Z]+)[|]+', text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        print(f'WARNING: {text} does not follow the pattern')
        return ''

df["Fetch"]=df["Test"].apply(clean_text)
```

regex explanation: `[|]+` consumes all pipes chars, then a group for upper case A-Z chars, `([A-Z])+`, and finally make sure that some (at least one) pipe is present with `[|]+`

However, it may be a bad workaround if you have a bigger problem, maybe you can provide more details on how you arrive to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

#### (1) If you just need to extract the first occurrence of such string:

You can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), as follows:

```
df['Fetch'] = df['Test'].str.extract(r'\|([^|]+)\|')
```

Regex `\|([^|]+)\|` is the simplest form you can use:

`\|`   matches the delimiter `|` before the target string

`(`    opening parenthesis for capturing group

`[^|]` character class for any character other than the delimiter `|`

`+`  quantifier for one or more occurrence(s)

`)`    opening parenthesis for capturing group

`\|`   matches the delimiter `|` after the target string

**Result:**

**Added 2 more rows for more test cases**

```
print(df)

                            Test   Fetch
0   |||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A  CHNBAD
1  |||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A|  CHNBAD
2           ||ABC||DEF|GHI|||JKL     ABC
```

#### (2) If you want to extract ALL the occurrences of such strings

You can use [`.str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), as follows:

```
df = df[['Test']].join(df['Test'].str.extractall(r'(?<=\|)([^|]+)(?=\|)').unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).rename(lambda x: 'Fetch_' + str(x+1), axis=1))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                            Test Fetch_1          Fetch_2 Fetch_3
0   |||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A  CHNBAD              NaN     NaN
1  |||||CHNBAD||POC-RM0EP7-01-A|  CHNBAD  POC-RM0EP7-01-A     NaN
2           ||ABC||DEF|GHI|||JKL     ABC              DEF     GHI
```

Here, we need a more complex regex so as to extract 3 matches from the last row.  If we use the previous regex, only 2 matches will be extracted.

If you want more explanation of the regex and codes, I can do it later, upon your request.